# Mostrar data pelo terminal

Tags: linux

Assim como você pode mudar a data do linux pelo terminal no formato {mês}{dia}{hora}{minuto}{ano}, tudo junto, eu queria saber como guardar a data atual em uma variável(Python), mudar a data e hora com um aplicativo de terminal e depois mudar de volta para a data na variável.

ex: date: Wed Nov 1 11:22:33 UTC 2015
preciso de ajuda em mostrar: 11(novembro)1(dia)11(hora)22(minuto)15(ano) sem os "()"

Comment: `11(novembro)1(dia)11(hora)22(minuto)15(ano)` sem os parênteses fica `111112215`. Não estão faltando uns espaços aí não?

Comment: nao, pra mudar a data pelo terminal e assim mesmo, mas o dia nao e "1" o certo e '01"

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Answer (score 2):

Bom, o manual do `date` é bem completo quanto ao formato. No seu caso, eu sugiro a seguinte linha de comando:

```
date +"%d%m%H%M%G"
```

onde em meu terminal, fornece a seguinte saída:

```
250211152016
```

PS. Dê uma olhada no manual do [date](https://linuxconfig.org/date-1-manual-page) para entender os formatos de saída

Comment: A resposta não me pareceu adequada. A pergunta é clara: "Guardar a data atual em uma variável Python".

Comment: @Lacobus uau, retaliação. Gostei disso. Vai para o seu curriculum aqui